# Sum of Even and Odd numbers includes numbers on outside of range, if if not even or odd

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

so this is my first term studying computer science and m currently learning Python. My assignment was to create a program to shows the sums of both odd and even numbers between to integers of your choice. It almost works, except for the fact that it adds the number defined as the range, not just the odds or evens within. Could anybody point out what I am doing wrong? Ive been stuck on this for a bit now. Thanks for the help!

I have defined the ranges and used the sum functions to find the sums, however the values i used for my range are included.

```
enter code here
print("Welcome to my Odd/Even sum generator.")
print("This program will show you the sum of all even and odd numbers between two integers of your choice.")
Num1 = int(input("What is your first, lower integer?"))
Num2 = int(input("What is your second, higher integer?"))


def sum_even(Num1, Num2):
    count1 = 0
    for i in range(Num1, Num2+1):
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            count1 += i
    return count1

def SumOdds(Num1,Num2):
  count2= Num1 + Num2 
  for i in range(Num1,Num2+1):
     if(i == Num1 or i == Num2):
         pass
     elif (int(i%2==1)):
        count2=count2+i

  print("The sum of the odd numbers is",(count2),".")
SumOdds(Num1,Num2)
print("The sum of the even numbers is",(sum_even(Num1, Num2)),".")
```

I want it to add the range values ONLY if those range values apply to the odd/even sum. Say, I input a range of 5 and 25. I would want the range values to be included in the sum for my OddSum but not my EvenSum.

Comment: *sum\_even* looks correct. Just copy / paste it (and negate the inner *if* condition) and you should be OK for *SumOdds*. Later on, when you'll be familiar with the language, you'll see that it's possible to write each function in a line of code :) .

Comment: As in delete the if statement?

Comment: No, *negate* and *delete* **are not** the same thing: `if(i % 2 != 0):`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, our instructor was gone for an entire week so I have had no-one to bounce this off of. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your issue is. If you were doing the range from 1 to 10, would you expect `1` and `10` in the sums or not? Presumably `1` would only be in the odd sum (since it's odd) and `10` would be in the even sum (since it's even). But neither of those should require special handling. Can you give an example of the input you give and the output you expect when your code is doing the wrong thing?

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have placed the following code in your SumOdds.

```
for i in range(Num1,Num2+1):
     if(i == Num1 or i == Num2):
         pass
```

This skips the first and last numbers, but if you move it to your sum_evens, your code should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks great, the changes which will help you are as follows:

```
def SumOdds(Num1,Num2):
    count2 = 0 # here ur adding NUM1+NUM2 by defualt initial it must be zero
    for i in range(Num1,Num2+1):
        if(i == Num1 or i == Num2):
            continue #If you don't want to consider the start and end so you can use continue 
        if (int(i%2==1)):
            count2+=i
    print(f"The sum of the odd numbers is: {count2}") # if your using above 3.5 python so u can use this type of formating also.

def sum_even(Num1, Num2):
    count1 = 0
    for i in range(Num1, Num2+1):
        if(i == Num1 or i == Num2):
            continue #If you don't want to consider the start and end so you can use continue 
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            count1 += i
    return count1

sum_of_odd = sum(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 != 0), range(Num1, Num2+1))) # Another way of doing
sum_of_even = sum(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0), range(Num1, Num2+1))) #Another way of doing
```